# Month duration input value in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

i have year,Month dropdown property and monthduration(input filed) property in text area.

can any one suggest me limit data or custom expression in table.

Year    Month   duration
2016    Apr 9

may
jun
jul
Aug
sep
Oct
nov
Dec
Jan 2017

above sample if user select year 2016 and month "Apr" and dropdown property and duration "9" (input filed ) means Apr + 9 months that would be jan 2017 values has to be displayed in Table.

can any one help me any limit data expression or custom expression.

Thanks
Naveen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHtap.png)

Comment: can you please edit your question a bit to make it more clear what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little difficult to understand but I'll give it a shot. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
# Assumptions: 3 document properties 
# 1) StartYear = Integer, The starting year the user selects from the listbox 
# 2) StartMonth = Integer, The starting month the user selects from the listbox (Can display as text (i.e. Apr.) but set to integer for actual property 
# 3) RangeMonth = Integer, number of months user inputs to add to date range.



(Year([DATECOL]) >= DocumentProperty("StartYear")) and Month([DATECOL]) > DocumentProperty("StartMonth") and 
 Year([DATECOL]) <= Year(DateAdd('month', DocumentProperty("RangeMonth"), Date(DocumentProperty("StartYear"), DocumentProperty("StartMonth"), 1))) and
 Month([DATECOL]) <= Month(DateAdd('month', DocumentProperty("RangeMonth"), Date(DocumentProperty("StartYear"), DocumentProperty("StartMonth"), 1)))
```

What is happening is first, you are ensuring DATECOL values are > the starting year and month. Then you are taking the starting year and month, adding the user input RangeMonth to that, and making sure DATECOL is <= that addition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.....its working fine but if i select "startMonth" as "Jan" and RangeMonth as "4" then i am getting Feb,Mar,Apr,May data except Jan month. Is it possible to get StartMonth "Jan" data also along with RangeMonth(Feb,Mar,Apr,May)....Thanks

Comment: Yes, change `Month([DATECOL]) > DocumentProperty("StartMonth")` to `Month([DATECOL]) >= DocumentProperty("StartMonth")`

If this is working, please accept this answer.

Comment: The same question was asked (and answered) here https://community.tibco.com/questions/month-duration-input-value-spotfire